# Change hyperlink to User Registration page instead of WordPress login page

Tags: comments, login, user-registration

It's confusing for unregistered users when they find this statement "You must be logged in to post a comment." takes them to the WordPress login page. As this is the case, I need to change it to user registration page.

Comment: There are many plugins such as [Pie Register](https://github.com/wp-plugins/pie-register) that exactly can do this for you.

Comment: I already have the registration form and I'm using woocommerce. I just need to change the hyperlink "logged in" to the log in page for users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your function.php:

```
$args = array('must_log_in'=> '<spam class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), HERE YOUR CUSTOM PAGE URL ) . '</spam>');
comment_form($args);
```

Comment: I added the code but it didn't solve the problem. I'm using woocommerce on my website.